# How do I route multiple domain names to the same amazon S3 bucket location?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, routes, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I have hosted react application on s3 bucket.
I want to access that same application with different domain name.
For Example:
www.example.com, www.demoapp.com, www.reactapp.com
I want to access s3 bucket hosted application with different domain.
How can I do that ?
Is there any other Amazon services do I need to use ?
if you have  done something like this then please help me.

Answer (score 2):

Use amazon cloudfront and you should be able to do this: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CNAMEs.html

You won't be able to do it as a standard s3 static website, but using cloud front will make it possible.

Answer (score 2):

Using Amazon CloudFront Distributions service we can achieve it.

1) Create new CloudFront Distributions service,

2) select the bucket name that you want to use

3) add multiple domain name which we want to add

4) CloudFront Distributions will generate new host something like 
      abcded.cloudfront.net

5) Add abcded.cloudfront.net that in our original domains CNAME record.

Answer (score -6):

If you are trying to route multiple domain names to the same S3 bucket then you are doing something wrong and you need to re-think your strategy.
domain names are meant to be a unique way of identifying resources on the internet (in this case its your S3 bucket) and there is no point of routing multiple domain names to the same S3 bucket.

If you really want to do this, then there are couple of options:

**Option one:**
Easy option is to point domain1.com to the S3 bucket and then have redirect rule that redirects requests to domain2.com and domain3.com to domain1.com.

**Option two:**
Another way is to create 3 S3 buckets and duplicate the content on all 3 and then use different domain names to point to each one. This of course is going to create a nightmare maintenance scenario as if you changed the application in one bucket then you have to do the same change in all other buckets. If you are using GIT to host your application then you can push to all 3 S3 bucket at once.

Again, all of the above is really nothing but a hack to get around the fact that domain names point to unique resources on the internet and I can't really see why would you do something like this.

Hope this gives you some insight on how to resolve this issue.

Comment: This is the cloud based app something like software as service. Because,  here multiple user will access their same application.

Comment: @motokazi can you link to any documentation or specifications that say domain names are supposed to point to **unique** resources? I'm not aware of any requirements or even *suggestions* that state two domain names should not point to the same resource.

Comment: @MarkB I have mentioned that domain names are **unique** way to identifying resources and not "a way to identify **unique** resources". They work the same way as addresses identifying houses. No 2 different addresses point to the same house. And although there is nothing stopping you from pointing 10 domain names to the same resource, the question is why would you do something like this? and take into account that the question is relating to S3 buckets which have unique names to start with and they are unique for a reason.

Comment: Ultimately DNS is just a service that resolves names to IP addresses. There is nothing that prevents you from resolving multiple names to the same IP address. People host multiple websites on the same server all the time. Also, people host the SAME website at multiple domains all the time. There is no reason they shouldn't be able to do so, and doing so is not *wrong*. Just because S3 has an artificial limitation that makes this a bit more difficult does not in itself make it wrong or a bad idea. Perhaps someone rebranded their website but still wants the old address to work?

Comment: @MarkB there is a nugget of truth here.  It technically *is* a bad idea, from an SEO perspective -- every "resource" should have a canonical URL and anything else should be a redirect.  However, that is only relevant with static, public content.  If these multiple domains have different content that is derived from the address bar, the argument fails to hold, since the content is unique, though the back-end is the same.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot you can fix that with a canonical meta tag in the html and stil have all the domains you want pointed to the same content.

Comment: @MarkB  It is application that is not for SEO purpose. Same application can access the different customer like Software as service. for example jira pms you can access entire same software on your domain. S3 website is reactApp